# How can I free up space from a failed VS2019 installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

My installation of Visual Studio 2019 failed, possibly due to the lack of command prompt privileges on my machine.

After getting the privileges, I found that I no longer have enough space to install it. The components I want require over 28GB of space, which I had before the failed installation that didn't clean up space when it failed.

How can I free up the required space? I tried Googling and also trying to identify the folder in which the download is stored, based on space utilization and the name of the folder, but I can't seem to identify it.

Where is the data from the failed installation stored and how can I clear it?

I tried running the installer and selecting "Remove" next to Visual Studio 2019, but it didn't free up the space. It just removed the entry from the installer.

Answer (score 0):

The folder is in the Packages folder specified during installation.